# "Get Groomed" Is it safe to use without negative connotation?

Tags: word-usage, slang, connotations

Can I ask someone to "Get Groomed" without any negative connotation?
Recently I came across [a post on hinative.com](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/4362645) which said:

> The second meaning is that it's an expression which means someone is taking advantage of another person by getting that person to like and trust them so that they could do whatever they want. Person A grooms Person B in order to abuse them sexually for example.

Also, does it apply only to men or also to women?

I am working on a beauty salon service. I was planning to use "Get groomed!" as a tagline. I want to be sure that it is not misconstrued.

Comment: Telling someone to 'get groomed' is implying that they're currently untidy. I imagine that most people would take that negatively.

Comment: Don't use "Get groomed" as a tagline for a hairdresser & beauty salon etc. in any **anglophone country**. Nowadays people rarely talk about how well-groomed (physically)  someone is.

Comment: What @Mari-LouA said. I'd guess at least 90% of all written instances of the verb ***groom*** in public discourse (newspapers, online blogs, etc.) over the past couple of decades would be in the context of paedophiles and other "sexual predators" lining up their next victim. Not a good choice for a business tagline.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd say 90% is [a gross overestimation](https://www.bostonglobe.com/2021/05/28/sports/is-matt-patricia-being-groomed-bill-belichicks-heir/).

Comment: "**Hair Styled to Suit You**"  :)

Answer (score 6):

*To groom* in its literal sense is usually applied to horses or dogs. The noun *groom* originally meant *man* (as in 'bridegroom'), but came to mean a servant who looks after horses.

As an extension of the meaning, you can describe a smartly-dressed person with tidy hair as *well-groomed*, and speak of *personal grooming* as the process of making *yourself* clean and tidy, but we don't normally speak of grooming a person except in the metaphorical sense. As you are aware, this is *to prepare someone for a future purpose* and has recently acquired the meaning of preparing a child for sexual exploitation.

So, it would be better to ask someone to smarten themselves up or get tidied up.

Comment: We DO commonly speak of [personal grooming](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22personal+grooming%22)

Comment: @GArthurBrown Indeed we do, but not normally of a person 'getting groomed'.

Comment: "but we don't normally speak of grooming a person" This should be reworded then.